# Root cronjob does not run correctly, user cronjob does

Tags: cron, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to run a root cronjob for executing a script.

Here's the cronjob I put into `sudo crontab -e`:

```
*/1 * * * * ~/temperature_log/logtemp.sh >> ~/temperature_log/templog.log>&1
```

The script requires root permission for `hddtemp`.
Unfortunately, the `templog.log` file never appears. The syslog says:

```
Jun  6 13:09:01 user CRON[32433]: (root) CMD (~/temperature_log/logtemp.sh >> ~/temperature_log/templog.log>&1)
Jun  6 13:09:01 user CRON[32426]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

So apparently, the script IS run, but something goes wrong from there.

Even stranger: If I run a user cron via just `crontab -e`, the script executes (without root permissions, though, so it is of no use for me) and does write the log file.

How can I make sure that my root crontab works correctly?

I am connecting to this computer via ssh as a user without root permissions, but I do have the root passwort.

**EDIT**

I changed the program now, I want it to log to syslog via `logger`. Again, running the script manually works and it logs correctly, but running it from crontab just shows this:

`Jun  6 14:27:01 user CRON[1657]: (root) CMD (Jun  6 15:06:01 insystems CRON[25328]: (root) CMD (/bin/sh ~/temperature_log/logtemp.sh)`

No information is logged. I added the /dev/null part to get rid of the email warning. I am not planning on installing an email service.

Comment: Have you written the script to send email alerts? The warning, "(No MTA installed, discarding output)", happens when a mail service is not installed.

Most Linux distributions have a mail service (including an MTA) installed. Ubuntu doesn't though.

You can install a mail service, postfix for example, to solve this problem.

sudo apt-get install postfix

Also, try providing the full path for the files (The absolute path):
~/temperature_log/logtemp.sh and ~/temperature_log/templog.log

Make sure logtemp.sh has execute permission. If no,issue command 

chmod +x logtemp.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to add the cronjob not to `crontab -e` but to `/etc/crontab`. From there, it worked without issues.

I probably made a mistake in the other crontab file, but this solution is okay for me.

Answer (score 3):

Have you written the script to send email alerts? The warning, "(No MTA installed, discarding output)", happens when a mail service is not installed.

Most Linux distributions have a mail service (including an MTA) installed. Ubuntu doesn't though.

You can install a mail service, postfix for example, to solve this problem.

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

Also, try providing the full path for the files (The absolute path):
~/temperature_log/logtemp.sh and ~/temperature_log/templog.log

Make sure logtemp.sh has execute permission. If no, then issue command

```
chmod +x logtemp.sh
```

Comment: I tried all those things, except the postfix. Why would I need a mail service if I just want to log to `syslog`?

Comment: Are you getting the desired output when you execute the script in shell?

Also try appending /bin/sh before calling the script. 

Example:  */1 * * * * /bin/sh /root/temperature_log/logtemp.sh >> /root/temperature_log/templog.log > &1

Comment: it works if I do `sudo sh logtemp.sh` (syslog: `Jun  6 14:43:08 user user: Temperature log: /dev/sda1: CT250MX500SSD1: 54°C`). But when cron calls it, all I get in the syslog (see my edit) is `Jun  6 14:43:01 user CRON[12283]: (root) CMD (/bin/sh ~/temperature_log/logtemp.sh)`